# adding functions to individual sites in a WPMU installation

Tags: php, function, wpmu

This is a bit of a rookie question but i cant seem to find any clear explanations elsewhere.

I have set up a WPMU installation that I am experimenting with. My question is the following. I have been using the functions.php file located within the theme folder of a normal wordpress installation. The functions added into this file would apply to all sites using that theme. How would i go about adding functions for individual sites? Is it as simple as adding a functions.php file to the root folder of that site? if so, what would the hierarchy of these files be?